# Grouping on elements in XML transformation with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am struggling with the concept of grouping (on multiple keys) of table based XML to hierarchy with XSLT

The grouping is based on first four elements, however the grouping **must** break if there is another element in between the set.

Source XML:

```
<RECORDS> 
<RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A1</F1>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A2</F1>
</RECORD>
 <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>195</E5>
    <F1>A3</F1>
  </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A4</F1>
  </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A5</F1>
  </RECORD>
     <RECORD>
    <E1>DONALD</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A6</F1>
  </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
    <E1>DONALD</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F1>A7</F1>
  </RECORD>
 </RECORDS>
```

Output XML

```
 <RECORDS>
 <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F>
     <F1>A1</F1>
     <F1>A2</F1>
    </F>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>195</E5>
    <F>
     <F1>A3</F1>
     <F1>A4</F1>
    </F>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
   <E1>MICKEY</E1> <!--Must break and not merge in first group -->
   <E2>TEST</E2>
   <E4>14</E4>
   <E5>196</E5>
   <F>   
   <F1>A5</F1>
   </F>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <E1>DONALD</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <E5>196</E5>
    <F>
     <F1>A6</F1>
     <F1>A7</F1>
    </F>
  </RECORD>
 </RECORDS>
```

Here is the XSL I have come up with so far...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="grouped" match="RECORD"
  use="concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5 )"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <RECORDS>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "RECORD[generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('grouped',
                        concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5 )
                          )
                           [1]
                      )
           ]
   "/>
  </RECORDS>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="RECORD">
   <RECORD>
  <E1><xsl:value-of select="E1"/></E1>
<E2><xsl:value-of select="E2"/></E2>
<E4><xsl:value-of select="E4"/></E4>
<F>
<xsl:for select="F1">
<F1><xsl:value-of select="F1"/></F1>
</xsl:for>

</F>
   </RECORD>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue is that I am unable to generate the inner  tag reapeating for each f1. Also I should get 4 set of RECORDS, not 3 that I get with this.

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <F></F>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <E1>MICKEY</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <F></F>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <E1>DONALD</E1>
    <E2>TEST</E2>
    <E4>14</E4>
    <F></F>
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Comment: Please pinpoint your difficulty - preferably, post your attempt so we can fix it.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is a solution using keys**. **Shorter** (28% less lines of code, and not requiring horizontal scrolling). **More Robust** (see the end of this answer for details)

It is more general, because it will work even in the case where in-between the elements we want to group, there are other elements that must be ignored (that is where `preceding-sibling::*[1]` may be an element we want excluded from grouping -- in the current problem -- not a `RECORD` element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kStartGroup" match="/*/*" use=
    "generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
      [not(concat(E1, '|', E2, '|', E4, '|', E5)
          = concat(current()/E1, '|', current()/E2, '|', current()/E4, '|', current()/E5)
          )
      ][1])"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[not(concat(E1, '|', E2, '|', E4, '|', E5) 
                            = 
                              concat(preceding-sibling::*[1]/E1, '|', 
                                     preceding-sibling::*[1]/E2, '|', 
                                     preceding-sibling::*[1]/E4, '|',
                                     preceding-sibling::*[1]/E5)
                             )]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="E1 | E2 | E4 | E5"/>
      <F><xsl:copy-of select=
                      "key('kStartGroup', generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1]))/F1"/></F>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>      
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Robustness / Scalability**

Because this transformation doesn't contain recursion (nested calls to `<xsl:apply-templates`), it is robust and scalable when applied on large XML files.

On the other side, the provided in another answer "siblings recursion" solution **crashes due to stack-overflow** when the transformation is applied on sufficiently-large XML document. In my case this crash was observed with source XML document of about 13 000 (13 thousand lines) -- this may vary depending on available RAM, XSLT processor, etc.

The current transformation executes successfully even on extremely large XML documents -- such as having 1 200 000 (one million and 200 thousand lines).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you want to do in XSLT 1.0 the equivalent of XSLT 2.0's `group-adjacent`. This can be achieved using a technique known as "sibling recursion":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/RECORDS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- start the first group -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECORD">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="E1 | E2 | E4 | E5"/>
        <F>
            <xsl:copy-of select="F1"/>
            <!-- immediate sibling in the same group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::RECORD[1][concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5) = $key]" mode="collect"/>
        </F>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- start the next group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::RECORD[not(concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5)=$key)][1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RECORD" mode="collect">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5)" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="F1"/>
    <!-- immediate sibling in the same group -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::RECORD[1][concat(E1, '+', E2, '+', E4 , '+', E5) = $key]" mode="collect" />
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Took me a while to understand, but got it finally